# Chrome is not showing the actual time taken to show the content in the network tab

Tags: java, google-chrome, vaadin7

When we tried to load the pdf in a popup window of our vaadin application, it takes some time to load the pdf preview. We inspected the time taken for the response through Chrome's network tab, it shows the response time in the network tab even before showing the pdf in the window.
[image]

The pdf has actually shown in the window after some time. This time difference is not showing in the response time. There is no additional request/response shown in the network tab.
[image]

Can anyone explain why the time to show the pdf in a window after receiving the response is not showing in the network tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The delay that you experience is most likely not caused by the network. The network tab only shows how long it took to download all the bytes from the server, but it doesn't include the time it takes for JavaScript running in the browser to process those bytes into something that can be shown on the screen.

To understand the whole process, you might want to record profiling data through the `Performance` tab. This will show where time is spent running JavaScript and rendering stuff on the screen.